# UITabBarItem click/touch event

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have declared a UITabBarController in my AppDelegate.m file.
I have two viewcontrollers in this UITabBarController.

In each of the views, lets call them view1 and view2, i have the following code:

```
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self)
    {
        UITabBarItem *tbi = self.tabBarItem;
        tbi.title = @"title";
        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
        tbi.image = i;
        tbi.tag = 0;
    }
```

This makes me able to freely navigate between two viewcontrollers.

Now, to the question:

I want to have an event when i click each of the tabs. I have googled for 4 hours now and tried a lot of things. I'm close to going insane.

Where do i put what kind of code to be able to execute something when i click each tab?

Please dont say " you need to implement UITabBarDelegate and then use -void(didselectitem) " without explaining exactly how :)

EDIT:
My AppDelegate.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PETTAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m file:

```
@implementation PETTAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];


PETTSoundBoardPage *sbP = [[PETTSoundBoardPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"PETTSoundBoardPage" bundle:appBundle];
PETTNPage * nP = [[PETTNPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"PETTNPage" bundle:appBundle];

UITabBarController *tBC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tBC.tabBarController.delegate = self;
tBC.viewControllers = @[sbP,nP];

self.window.rootViewController = tBC;


self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

sbP and nP file (almost identical code except for title and picture):

```
-(instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if(self)
{
    UITabBarItem *tbi = self.tabBarItem;
    tbi.title = @"Soundboard";
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
    tbi.image = i;
    tbi.tag = 0;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your event?

Comment: @nlee918
I'm trying to play a little click-like sound when they press each tab, from a mp3 file i have.

But to do that i first need to find some area of code that will run every time the user clicks each tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method, `didSelectViewController:`. I'm assuming that you have already prepared the sound playing method, so implement it as such in your AppDelegate.

Of course, you have to add the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to your interface as well by doing this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Add this code to your .m file of your app delegate.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

//Play your sound here

}
```

Info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

EDIT: You need to set your tabBarController's delegate to yourself. To do that do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //get reference to your view controller,

    myViewController.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!

However, i dont know where or how to implement the delegate, since my viewcontroller is a XIB file (interface builder)

Should i implement the method in the AppDelegate, or in each of the viewcontroller classes?

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough. This is in your app delegate.

Comment: @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

Comment: Thats also in your delegate

Comment: thanks for the quick responses! -However, i still cant get it working. i now have the @interface UITabBarDelegate in the AppDelegate.h file, and the code you posted inn the AppDelegate.m file.

To test, i just wrote NSLog(@"123"); inside the method, but the string doesnt appear in console, so it doesnt respond when i click each tab :/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you to set the delegate to self. Check my edit.

Comment: Still doesn't work, i edited and added a lot of info

Comment: Is that all you have in your App delegate?

Comment: the .h file is all i have yes.

i also have the method you posted

Comment: Change tBC.tabBarController.delegate = self; to tBC.delegate = self;

Comment: Finally! After 5 hours of trying to figure all this out! Worked now, thanks a lot! :)